# Is it possible to hide user list from the power button in top right corner?

Tags: settings, user-interface, user

is it possible to hide user list from the power button in top right corner? There are many users in the system and the menu stretches all over the screen.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but here's a possible workaround for you:  remove the Wingpanel and add the Application Menu to the Plank. Information on how to do this can be found here: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17213/how-to-stop-wingpanel-starting-up/17255#17255