# How to stop wingpanel starting up?

Tags: wingpanel

I want to try either no top panel or maybe something else. I assume I can do this by putting a .desktop in an autostart directory, but how to stop Wingpanel loading at start?

Comment: Is this for Juno?

Answer (score 1):

For Juno:

**1)** Install `dconf-editor`

**2)** Run `dconf-editor` and go to `/io/elementary/desktop/cerbere/monitored-processes`

**3)** Uncheck `"Use default value"`

**4)** Remove `'Wingpanel'` in Custom Value

**5)** Log out and then log back in.

If you do this, I highly recommend adding the application menu to Plank:

**1)** Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and alternate-click anywhere on the Plank.

**2)** Select `Preferences.`

**3)** Click the `Docklets` tab.

**4)** Double-click `Applications`

Now you can access your applications without the Wingpanel.

To have wingpanel start automatically again, either select `"Use default value"` or put `'wingpanel'` back into the Custom Value in dconf-editor.

To start wingpanel manually, open a terminal and type `wingpanel`.

Here's what the edited dconf window should look like:

[image]

Here's what my desktop looks like without the Wingpanel. It also has the Application Menu on the Plank.

[image]