# How to hide wingpanel or move to the side?

Tags: wingpanel, desktop, release-hera

I'm running elementary (Hera) on a small 11" widescreen laptop.

I'd like to have wingpanel either hidden or on the side of the screen so I don't lose any vertical space for working. Is that something that's doable?

Comment: Try my answer to this question: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17213/how-to-stop-wingpanel-starting-up/17255#17255

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet incorporated

You can try test this : https://github.com/mlibre/hide-wingpanel

Answer (score 0):

The "painless" option that comes to my mind is to force application you use to go fullscreen. You can even define keyboard shortcut in order to do that easily. 
System settings - Keyboard - Shortcust - Window - Toggle Fullscreen.